# How to do Debugging Test Cases of Robot Framework in Pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, automation, pycharm, robotframework

I am unable to debug any test case of Robot Framework in Pycharm Community version. Is there any simple way to start the debugging through breakpoints like eclipse?

I tried to set up with the instruction provided here : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007703060-Debugging-python-code-when-running-Robot-Framework-tests but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Open Pycharm and go to right side and open edit Configuration where you can edit Run/Debug configuration

[image: 1]

Click on Plus icon showing at top left corner, Select Robot Framework and Set Configuration as per defined in Image and save configuration. Note: Target .robot or folder to run should be your project\testcase path

[image: 2]

Select saved setting for debug Robot file

[image: 3]

Put debugger from where you want to debug and click on debug icon. It will work.

Comment: Putting debugging point in .robot file is not happening in pycharm

Comment: Hey @SayanGanguli use robot framework Language Server plugin, create Robot file, and as usual how we are put debug point at code line by double click on near code line number, you will see red dot. Debug option will not come in right click as far as i know. once you put debugger. then process my commented steps. As per my setup in Pycharm , I am able to debug Robot file and even python file successful. and even i can run it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).